How do I disable the Upgrade to Ubunut 24.04.1 LTS spammer
Since Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS came out, every day, I get a reminder that I need to upgrade.  I am a grown up, I know this.  I don't need to be spammed every day by a reminder.  How do I make it stop?
As an aside, I attempted to update to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS when it was fresh out and the new kernel didn't recognise my raid controller.  So I'm hoping they've added it to 24.04.1 but I have a good reason for being cautious.
Now I know it is possible to completely disable update notifications (as explained in the answer to a question relating to Ubuntu 11), but that misses the point.  Before the 24.04.1 release, even when there was a major upgrade available, it wouldn't spam daily, with a critical alert, saying it was available.  It would simple give a note when you did updates.
What I'm asking is how to switch the 22.04.1 desktop to behave the same as before, and sure warn about updates, but not with a popup every day.

Be aware, that if you change the prompt to never, that's what it does... ie. you'll need to remember to release-upgrade before/when the release reaches EOSS or EOL, as never will stop all prompting forever.

Quite, thats my concern.  I'd be ok with being spammed periodically, but not every day

I'm also ok, with the icon showing something in the systray, that reminds me I need to do something, its the pingedy ping, when the cron job figures it out, or the multiple pingedy pings when I activate my computer after a couple of days, that I'd like to disable.
